# How to round corners of list item at the top and bottom of the list view? (not only for top and bottom items)

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with rounded corner at the top and the bottom. Look like this image: 
[image]

But when I click on the top and the bottom of ListView, the List Item's background is rectangle not rounded as background of ListView at top and bottom. Like this image :

[image: List item's corner not rounded]

How to resolve this issue?

this is my code :

1/ list_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cacaca">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_border"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

2/ list_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#fff"/>
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

3/ list_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
</selector>
```

4/ ListActivity.java

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView3);

ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
    listItems.add(""+i);
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, listItems);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Don't set drawable to Listview rather set top corner drawable to top item and bottom corner drawable to last item.

Comment: @Surender Kumar : Yes thanks, but i want listview with bottom and top rounded corner, not rounded corner for the first and last list items. but i want when i click on list item on the top and bottom listview it's corner rounded overlap the listview.

Comment: @HuoChhenleng Have you considered wrapping your `ListView` in a [`CardView`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/material/lists-cards.html)? You could put the entire list inside a `CardView` (instead of each item), and then set `card_view:cardCornerRadius` and `android:elevation` to your liking.

Comment: @Bryan : I will try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is not pretty but it does what you want. The idea is to invert the corner and draw them as foreground :

the `ListView` is wrapped in a `FrameLayout` :

```
<FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:foreground="@drawable/inverted_corners"
      android:layout_weight="1">
      <ListView
          android:id="@+id/listView3"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#fff"
          android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
  </FrameLayout>
```

which foreground (`drawable/inverted_corners.xml`) is set to a rounded *hole*, drawn with the background color. The trick is to draw a *line* outside the shape, instead of a filled shape :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="-11dp"
        android:left="-11dp"
        android:right="-11dp"
        android:top="-11dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="#cacaca" />
            <corners android:radius="22dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This garanties that the rounded corners are on top of the selector, and the overscroll effect.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily by using Android's support library's `CardView`. Just wrap your `ListView` in a `CardView` layout and set a `cardCornerRadius` to the `CardView`, like this:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#cacaca">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Dont forgot to import the `CardView`'s support library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: Hi bro. Now i test your solution again and again it not work. why?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should set the layout with corners to your `ListView`'s first and last element, but not to the whole `ListView`.

You can create two extra .xml files in addition to your `list_selector.xml`: one for first element with the round corners at the top (lets call it `list_selector_top.xml`) and another one for the last element with the round corners at the bottom (`list_selector_bottom.xml`).

Then you can create your own `MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter` and somewhere in `getView()` method set the appropriate background to your element's `View` (if `position==0` set `list_selector_top.xml`, if `position==getCount()-1` set `list_selector_bottom.xml`, by default set `list_selector.xml`).

It might be not the simpliest approach, but it works.

Comment: Yes thank you, but i want the listview to rounded corner and when click on the item on the top and bottom listview, it's corner rounded overlap the listview, not only for the first and last item.

Answer (score 1):

Set your corner radius to `list view` selector also using this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        >
        <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        <corners
            android:radius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
        </item>

</selector>
```

so your selection will not be cross boundry of `list view`.

[image]

*cons* - you will not able to define which `radius` you have to set as per top and bottom part that is why have to set `radius` to all sides.

hope this should help or at least give you some direction to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `FrameLayout` as parent to the `ListView`, then set the cornered shape as `foreground` to the parent `FrameLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foreground="@drawable/list_border">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

If you want to use LinearLayout as parent of ListView, then surround your `ListView` with `ForegroundLinearLayout` and set the cornered shape as `foreground` to the `ForegroundLinearLayout`.

What is `ForegroundLinearLayout`? It is `LinearLayout` with Foreground property like `FrameLayout`. Get the code from Chris Banes. https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/9091754

Your code should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ForegroundLinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foreground="@drawable/list_border">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"/>
</ForegroundLinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

please add padding in your style.i updated style here.
2 list_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#fff"/>
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
<padding android:left="10dp"
      android:right="10dp"
      android:top="10dp"
      android:bottom="10dp"
      />
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks. But the item is not match_parent.